# Java Inheritance and method overriding program

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have the following exercise regarding inheritance and methods overriding, and the question is why the 'System.out.println(f1)' in the 'initialize()' method in the parent class is called with param '0', and what is needed to do to for it will be called with param '6'. Please help me understand it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B(6);
}

public static class A {
    private int f1 = 7;

    public A(int f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    protected int f1 = 3;

    public B(int f1) {
        super(f1);
        this.f1 += f1;
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `initialize` doesn't have *any* parameters... and you're not overriding it in `B` because it's a private method. It's unclear what you're expecting and why, to be honest - but the fact that you've got two fields with the same name is only going to be adding to the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privare methods cannot be overriden. You can write the method in child but practically it is not overriding
From the Java language specification [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

> Note that a private method cannot be hidden or overridden in the technical sense of those terms. This means that a subclass can declare a method with the same signature as a private method in one of its superclasses, and there is no requirement that the return type or throws clause of such a method bear any relationship to those of the private method in the superclass.

Your parent method is not getting called with parameter value as 0. if you can see parent's constructor is overriding the value `this.f1=f1` the value of `f1` will be 6. Therefore output will be 6 and 9.

Comment: Thanks for JLS link, it helped me a lot not only for this exercise!